# Python 3 Tkinter - Create Text Widget covering 100% Width with Grid

Tags: python, text, tkinter, grid

I know that you can easily create a Tkinter Text widget that covers 100% of the width using the Pack Geometry Manager:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
textWidget = Text(root)
textWidget.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
root.geometry('600x1000')
root.mainloop()
```

But I was wondering, how do I accomplish this same task using the Grid Geometry Manager with grid_columnconfigure?

Comment: Do you know how to use grid? Have you read the documentation? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using column configure with grid to solve the problem, but I do not quite understand the documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using grid requires these steps:

- use the `grid` method of the text widget, giving it a row and column. In this case 
  you can use 0,0.
- also with the `grid` method, define whether or not you want the widget to "stick"
  to the sides of the space it was given. In your case you do, so you can give the
  string "nsew" (north, south, east, west).
- configure the row that the widget is in to have a weight of 1 (one). Do this with
  `grid_rowconfigure`. This will cause the row to expand vertically to fill any extra space
- configure the column that the widget is in to have a weight of 1 (one). Do this with
  `grid_columnconfigure`. This will cause the column to expand horizontally to fill 
  any extra space.

Note that `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` are methods to be called on the
widget that *contains* the text widget, not on the text widget itself. The `grid` method is
called on the text widget, because you are telling the text widget where it should place
itself in its parent.

You code would look like this:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
textWidget = Text(root)

textWidget.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.geometry('600x1000')
root.mainloop()
```

When you have a single widget that is to fill all of the space allotted to it, I recommend `pack` simply because you can do everything with one line of code rather than three. `pack` is perfect for this type of problem. `grid` is more suited to creating a grid of widgets, as its name applies. That being said, either is perfectly acceptable. You can mix and match `grid` and `pack` within the same program, though you can't use them both for widgets that share a common parent.