# Why is not presented the custoned widget

Tags: tkinter

I want to present the left customed widget 3 times. Left, center and right.

I have trying to follow and mix some examples I have found, but I only get one widget presented.

I have added colout to get some clues, but I am not able to find what I am doing wrong.

This is the code:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
#import tkinter.ttk, Font, Label, Frame as tk
#import tkinter.ttk as tk

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614037/python-3-tkinter-create-text-widget-covering-100-width-with-grid?rq=1
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591294/how-to-create-a-self-resizing-grid-of-buttons-in-tkinter
# http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

# 02. Pruebo cambiando llamada de funcion de clase a metodo de instancia  

class   Cuadro(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kargs):

        # super().__init__(root)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kargs)

        #Create & Configure frame 

        frame = tk.Frame(parent)       
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW")



        #Create a 3x3 (rows x columns) grid of labels inside the frame
        for row_index in range(3):
        #tk.Grid.rowconfigure(frame, row_index, weight=1)               # version 02
            frame.rowconfigure(row_index, weight=1)                     # version 02
            for col_index in range(3):
                #tk.Grid.columnconfigure(frame, col_index, weight=1)    # version 02
                frame.columnconfigure(col_index, weight=1)              # version 02
                lbl = tk.Label(frame, text = str((row_index *3) + col_index + 1)) #create a button inside frame 
                #lbl.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky=N+S+E+W)
                lbl.grid(row=row_index, column=col_index, sticky="NSEW")



#Create & Configure root
class   Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        tk.Grid.rowconfigure   (parent, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(parent, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(parent, 1, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(parent, 2, weight=1)
        self.cuadro1 = Cuadro(parent)
        self.cuadro1.config(background="red")
        self.cuadro1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NSEW")     
        self.cuadro2 = Cuadro(parent)
        self.cuadro2.config(bg="green")
        self.cuadro2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="NSEW")
        self.cuadro3 = Cuadro(parent)
        self.cuadro3.config(bg="blue")
        self.cuadro3.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="NSEW")


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title(sys.argv[0])    # version 02

    myapp = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is the result:

![http://imgur.com/XROp68R](https://imgur.com/XROp68R)

What is wrong?

Comment: 4 times or 3 times? you said left cent and right. That is only 3.

Comment: Excuse me! Tipyng mistake. :-(. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your three Cuadro objects *have no contents at all* - they're valid Frames, since you inherited from tk.Frame and called the superclass `__init__()`, but you did absolutely nothing with them.  Instead, each one created an entirely separate Frame, not connected to the Cuadro itself, and placed it at row=0, column=0 in the parent view.  Each of these overwrote the previous one, and the red Cuadro which was originally placed at row=0, column=0, so you ended up with a single visible copy of the 3x3 grid, and no red area.

You made the same mistake with Application - it's a valid Frame, but you added nothing to it, instead you created each Cuadro as a direct child of Application's parent (the Tk root window).

It's perfectly valid to have classes that merely create widgets like this, but they shouldn't derive from a Tk widget class if you aren't going to use them as widgets themselves.

Comment: As you indicate I have changed the dependency from  parent to self in Cuadro and Application class,
and adding init frame in Application class
Now it is shown the three Cuadro's, but does not resize them , nor accept the background color.
What do I continue to do wrong or what do I lack?

TAnd this is the new result:

!http://imgur.com/QfoF7cQ

when resize it:

!http://imgur.com/8FavoIL

Sorry. I don not know how to add the new code. :-(

Comment: I think I have found the solution, following your ideas, inserting  

`    tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
    tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)`

 after  
 
`    root = tk.Tk()`

Comment: That's a strange way of writing it, should simply be `root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)`.

Comment: I take note of this!  Your comments have been very helpful!